# Xcode isn't recognizing what "frame" and "addChild" is?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite, skspritenode

For some reason, Xcode is saying `Use of unresolved identifier 'frame'` and `Use of unresolved identifier 'addChild'`
 I don't understand why it isn't recognizing this code because I used "frame" and "addChild" earlier on in this program in another function which has no errors.

I found this in the activity log:

> /Users/xxxxxxx/Desktop/Cave Run/Cave Run/Scenes/GameScene.swift:52:38: error: use of unresolved identifier
>   'frame'
>       BrickBlock.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
>                                        ^~~~~ /Users/xxxxxxxx/Desktop/Cave Run/Cave
>   Run/Scenes/GameScene.swift:52:53: error: use of unresolved identifier
>   'frame'
>       BrickBlock.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
>                                                       ^~~~~ /Users/xxxxxxxx/Desktop/Cave Run/Cave Run/Scenes/GameScene.swift:53:5:
>   error: use of unresolved identifier 'addChild'
>       addChild(BrickBlock)
>       ^~~~~~~~ :0: warning: 'GLKTextureLoaderErrorDomain' was deprecated in iOS 12.0: OpenGLES API deprecated. (Define
>   GLES_SILENCE_DEPRECATION to silence these warnings)

```
func spawnBrickBlock() {
    let BrickBlock = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Basic Brick")
    BrickBlock.size = CGSize(width: 170, height: 170)
    BrickBlock.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
    addChild(BrickBlock)    
}
```

Comment: Is that code inside a view controller subclass? Can you post the code of the whole class?

Comment: The problem is that 'addChild()' and 'frame' belong to 'UIViewController' or 'SKNode'.

Comment: So how to I fix this?

Comment: You have to move that function to a subclass of either `UIViewController` or `SKNode`.